# Shading confidence intervals in R - base R if possible

Tags: r, statistics, polygon, confidence-interval, loess

I am comparing two lines that were regressed using LOESS. I want to display the confidence intervals of the two lines clearly, and I am having some difficulties.

I have tried using a variety of line types and colors, but the result is still to busy and messy in my opinion. I think that shading between the confidence intervals might make things clearer, but I am having some difficulties wrapping my head around the problem considering how my coding is structured so far. I have included the produced plot, the data for the two sets Analysis5k and Analysis5kz, and my code up to this point.

I have seen some examples where two polygons were overlapped to show where the confidence intervals overlap which seems like it might be a good way to present the data. If there was a way to draw the polygon in the area that is shared by the two confidence intervals, that might be another good way to present the data.

I understand the basic concept of how the polygon should be done, but the examples I have found have been applied to much more simplistic lines and data. Part of this is my own fault for some poor organization up to this point, but as this step is basically the finishing touch on my data presentation, I really don't want to have to rework everything from ground up.

Any help or insight is greatly appreciated.

***UPDATE***

I updated the Title. I received some great examples using ggplot, and while I would like to get around to working with ggplot in the future, I have only dealt with base R up to this point. For this particular project would like to try to keep this in base R if possible.  [image: plot without shading]

Analysis5k

```
Period  15p5    Total_5plus
-4350   0.100529101 12.6
-3900   0.4 20
-3650   0.0625  9.6
-3900   0.126984127 16.8
-3958   0.133333333 5
-4350   0.150943396 10.6
-3400   0.146341463 8.2
-3650   0.255319149 9.4
-3400   0.222222222 9
-3500   0.245014245 39
-3600   0.125   8
-3808   0.1 20
-3900   0.160493827 18
-3958   0.238095238 7
-4058   0.2 5
-3500   0.086956522 28.75
-4117   0.141414141 6.6
-4350   0.171038825 31.76666667
-4350   0.166666667 6
-3650   0.143798024 30.36666667
-2715   0.137931034 7.25
-4350   0.235588972 26.6
-3500   0.228840125 79.75
-4350   0.041666667 8
-3650   0.174757282 20.6
-2715   0.377777778 11.25
-3500   0.2 7.5
-3650   0.078947368 7.6
-3400   0.208333333 24
-4233   0.184027778 19.2
-3650   0.285714286 12.6
-4350   0.166666667 6
```

Analysis5kz

```
Period  15p5    Total_5plus
-4350   0.100529101 12.6
-4350   0   5
-3900   0.4 20
-3650   0.0625  9.6
-3400   0   6
-3900   0.126984127 16.8
-3958   0.133333333 5
-4350   0.150943396 10.6
-3400   0.146341463 8.2
-3650   0.255319149 9.4
-3400   0.222222222 9
-3500   0.245014245 39
-3600   0.125   8
-3650   0   28
-3808   0.1 20
-3900   0.160493827 18
-3958   0.238095238 7
-4058   0.2 5
-3500   0   25
-3500   0.086956522 28.75
-4117   0.141414141 6.6
-4350   0.171038825 31.76666667
-4350   0.166666667 6
-3650   0.143798024 30.36666667
-2715   0.137931034 7.25
-4350   0.235588972 26.6
-3500   0.228840125 79.75
-4350   0.041666667 8
-3500   0   5
-3650   0.174757282 20.6
-3800   0   9
-2715   0.377777778 11.25
-3500   0.2 7.5
-3650   0.078947368 7.6
-4117   0   8
-4350   0   8
-3400   0.208333333 24
-4233   0.184027778 19.2
-3025   0   7
-3650   0.285714286 12.6
-4350   0.166666667 6
```

Code

```
  ppi <- 300 
  png("5+ KC shaded CI.png", width=6*ppi, height=6*ppi, res=ppi) 
  library(Hmisc) 
  Analysis5k <- read.csv(file.choose(), header = T) 
  Analysis5kz <- read.csv(file.choose(), header = T)
  par(mfrow = c(1,1), pty = "s", oma=c(1,2,1,1), mar=c(4,4,2,2)) 
  plot(X15p5 ~ Period, Analysis5kz, xaxt = "n", yaxt= "n", ylim=c(-0.2,0.7), xlim=c(-5000,-2500), xlab = "Years B.P.", ylab = expression(''[15]*'p'[5]), main = "") 
  vx <- seq(-5000,-2000, by = 500) 
  vy <- seq(-0.2,0.7, by = 0.1) 
  axis(1, at = vx) 
  axis(2, at = vy) 
  a5k <- order(Analysis5k$Period) 
  a5kz <- order(Analysis5kz$Period)
  Analysis5k.lo <- loess(X15p5 ~ Period, Analysis5k, weights = Total_5plus, span = 0.6) 
  Analysis5kz.lo <- loess(X15p5 ~ Period, Analysis5kz, weights = Total_5plus, span = 0.6)      
  pred5k <- predict(Analysis5k.lo, se = TRUE) 
  pred5kz <- predict(Analysis5kz.lo, se = TRUE)      
  lines(Analysis5k$Period[a5k], pred5k$fit[a5k], col="blue", lwd=2) 
  lines(Analysis5kz$Period[a5kz], pred5kz$fit[a5kz], col="skyblue", lwd=2)          
  lines(Analysis5K$Period[a5K], pred5K$fit[a5K] - qt(0.975, pred5K$df)*pred5K$se[a5K],col="blue",lty=2) 
  lines(Analysis5K$Period[a5K], pred5K$fit[a5K] + qt(0.975, pred5K$df)*pred5K$se[a5K],col="blue",lty=2)      
  lines(Analysis5Kz$Period[a5Kz], pred5Kz$fit[a5Kz] - qt(0.975, pred5Kz$df)*pred5Kz$se[a5Kz],col="skyblue",lty=2) 
  lines(Analysis5Kz$Period[a5Kz], pred5Kz$fit[a5Kz] + qt(0.975, pred5Kz$df)*pred5Kz$se[a5Kz],col="skyblue",lty=2)
  abline(h=0.173, lty=3) 
  abline(v=-4700, lty=3)
  abline(v=-4000, lty=3)
  abline(v=-3000, lty=3)
  minor.tick(nx=5, ny=4, tick.ratio=0.5) 
  dev.off()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a solution with base plot based on your code.

The trick with `polygon` is that you must provide 2 times the x coordinates in one vector, once in normal order and once in reverse order (with function `rev`) and you must provide the y coordinates as a vector of the upper bounds followed by the lower bounds in reverse order.

We use the `adjustcolor` function to make standard colors transparent.

```
library(Hmisc) 
ppi <- 300 
par(mfrow = c(1,1), pty = "s", oma=c(1,2,1,1), mar=c(4,4,2,2)) 
plot(X15p5 ~ Period, Analysis5kz, xaxt = "n", yaxt= "n", ylim=c(-0.2,0.7), xlim=c(-5000,-2500), xlab = "Years B.P.", ylab = expression(''[15]*'p'[5]), main = "") 
vx <- seq(-5000,-2000, by = 500) 
vy <- seq(-0.2,0.7, by = 0.1) 
axis(1, at = vx) 
axis(2, at = vy) 
a5k <- order(Analysis5k$Period) 
a5kz <- order(Analysis5kz$Period)
Analysis5k.lo <- loess(X15p5 ~ Period, Analysis5k, weights = Total_5plus, span = 0.6) 
Analysis5kz.lo <- loess(X15p5 ~ Period, Analysis5kz, weights = Total_5plus, span = 0.6)      
pred5k <- predict(Analysis5k.lo, se = TRUE) 
pred5kz <- predict(Analysis5kz.lo, se = TRUE)      

polygon(x = c(Analysis5k$Period[a5k], rev(Analysis5k$Period[a5k])),
        y = c(pred5k$fit[a5k] - qt(0.975, pred5k$df)*pred5k$se[a5k], 
              rev(pred5k$fit[a5k] + qt(0.975, pred5k$df)*pred5k$se[a5k])),
        col =  adjustcolor("dodgerblue", alpha.f = 0.10), border = NA)

polygon(x = c(Analysis5kz$Period[a5kz], rev(Analysis5kz$Period[a5kz])),
        y = c(pred5kz$fit[a5kz] - qt(0.975, pred5kz$df)*pred5kz$se[a5kz], 
              rev( pred5kz$fit[a5kz] + qt(0.975, pred5kz$df)*pred5kz$se[a5kz])),
        col =  adjustcolor("orangered", alpha.f = 0.10), border = NA)

lines(Analysis5k$Period[a5k], pred5k$fit[a5k], col="dodgerblue", lwd=2) 
lines(Analysis5kz$Period[a5kz], pred5kz$fit[a5kz], col="orangered", lwd=2)   

abline(h=0.173, lty=3) 
abline(v=-4700, lty=3)
abline(v=-4000, lty=3)
abline(v=-3000, lty=3)
minor.tick(nx=5, ny=4, tick.ratio=0.5)
```

[image]

Comment: Looks perfect. The ggplot methods were great too, but this will cut out a ton of extra work for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it with ggplot:

(1) Apply the loess smoothing to both data.sets

```
library(dplyr)
df.lo <- lapply(datlist, function(x)loess(X15p5 ~ Period, data=x, weights = Total_5plus, span = 0.6))
```

(2) create a new data.frame that expand the min (-4350) and max Period (-2715) of data.set:

```
nd1 <- nd2 <- expand.grid(Period=seq(-4350, -2715, length=100))
```

(3) predict the fit and se for each of the loess smoother and bind into a single data.frame:

```
nd1[,c("fit", "se")] <- predict(df1.lo[[1]], newdata=nd1, se=T)[1:2]
nd1 <- nd1 %>% mutate(group="5k")
nd2[,c("fit", "se")] <- predict(df2.lo[[2]], newdata=nd1, se=T)[1:2]
nd2 <- nd2 %>% mutate(group="5kz")

ndata <- rbind(nd1, nd2)
```

(4) With the predicted data, use `ggplot2::geom_ribbon` to show overlapping se:

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(ndata, aes(Period, fit)) + 
  geom_line(aes(colour=group)) + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=fit-1.96*se, ymax=fit+1.96*se, fill=group), alpha=.2) 

p
```

[image]

(5) add data points and abline:

```
dat <- do.call(rbind, datlist)
p + 
  geom_point(data=dat, aes(y=X15p5, shape=as.factor(group)), alpha=.2) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept=0.173, linetype="dotted") + 
  geom_vline(xintercept=c(-4700, -4000, -3000), linetype="dotted") +
  ylab("X15p5") + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

The source data `datlist` is the list of the two data.frames "Analysis5k" and "Analysis5kz". The dput as follow:

```
structure(list(`5k` = structure(list(Period = c(-4350L, -3900L, 
-3650L, -3900L, -3958L, -4350L, -3400L, -3650L, -3400L, -3500L, 
-3600L, -3808L, -3900L, -3958L, -4058L, -3500L, -4117L, -4350L, 
-4350L, -3650L, -2715L, -4350L, -3500L, -4350L, -3650L, -2715L, 
-3500L, -3650L, -3400L, -4233L, -3650L, -4350L), X15p5 = c(0.100529101, 
0.4, 0.0625, 0.126984127, 0.133333333, 0.150943396, 0.146341463, 
0.255319149, 0.222222222, 0.245014245, 0.125, 0.1, 0.160493827, 
0.238095238, 0.2, 0.086956522, 0.141414141, 0.171038825, 0.166666667, 
0.143798024, 0.137931034, 0.235588972, 0.228840125, 0.041666667, 
0.174757282, 0.377777778, 0.2, 0.078947368, 0.208333333, 0.184027778, 
0.285714286, 0.166666667), Total_5plus = c(12.6, 20, 9.6, 16.8, 
5, 10.6, 8.2, 9.4, 9, 39, 8, 20, 18, 7, 5, 28.75, 6.6, 31.76666667, 
6, 30.36666667, 7.25, 26.6, 79.75, 8, 20.6, 11.25, 7.5, 7.6, 
24, 19.2, 12.6, 6), group = c("5k", "5k", "5k", "5k", "5k", "5k", 
"5k", "5k", "5k", "5k", "5k", "5k", "5k", "5k", "5k", "5k", "5k", 
"5k", "5k", "5k", "5k", "5k", "5k", "5k", "5k", "5k", "5k", "5k", 
"5k", "5k", "5k", "5k")), .Names = c("Period", "X15p5", "Total_5plus", 
"group"), row.names = c(NA, 32L), class = "data.frame"), `5kz` = 
structure(list(
    Period = c(-4350L, -4350L, -3900L, -3650L, -3400L, -3900L, 
    -3958L, -4350L, -3400L, -3650L, -3400L, -3500L, -3600L, -3650L, 
    -3808L, -3900L, -3958L, -4058L, -3500L, -3500L, -4117L, -4350L, 
    -4350L, -3650L, -2715L, -4350L, -3500L, -4350L, -3500L, -3650L, 
    -3800L, -2715L, -3500L, -3650L, -4117L, -4350L, -3400L, -4233L, 
    -3025L, -3650L, -4350L), X15p5 = c(0.100529101, 0, 0.4, 0.0625, 
    0, 0.126984127, 0.133333333, 0.150943396, 0.146341463, 0.255319149, 
    0.222222222, 0.245014245, 0.125, 0, 0.1, 0.160493827, 0.238095238, 
    0.2, 0, 0.086956522, 0.141414141, 0.171038825, 0.166666667, 
    0.143798024, 0.137931034, 0.235588972, 0.228840125, 0.041666667, 
    0, 0.174757282, 0, 0.377777778, 0.2, 0.078947368, 0, 0, 0.208333333, 
    0.184027778, 0, 0.285714286, 0.166666667), Total_5plus = c(12.6, 
    5, 20, 9.6, 6, 16.8, 5, 10.6, 8.2, 9.4, 9, 39, 8, 28, 20, 
    18, 7, 5, 25, 28.75, 6.6, 31.76666667, 6, 30.36666667, 7.25, 
    26.6, 79.75, 8, 5, 20.6, 9, 11.25, 7.5, 7.6, 8, 8, 24, 19.2, 
    7, 12.6, 6), group = c("5kz", "5kz", "5kz", "5kz", "5kz", 
    "5kz", "5kz", "5kz", "5kz", "5kz", "5kz", "5kz", "5kz", "5kz", 
    "5kz", "5kz", "5kz", "5kz", "5kz", "5kz", "5kz", "5kz", "5kz", 
    "5kz", "5kz", "5kz", "5kz", "5kz", "5kz", "5kz", "5kz", "5kz", 
    "5kz", "5kz", "5kz", "5kz", "5kz", "5kz", "5kz", "5kz", "5kz"
    )), .Names = c("Period", "X15p5", "Total_5plus", "group"), row.names = 33:73, class = "data.frame")), .Names = c("5k", 
"5kz"))
```

Comment: Thanks Adam. It looks great. If possible I would like to try to finish this in base R though. I really like the example you provided and want to try using ggplot for work like this in the future, but I have a large number of figures that I have tried to standardize in this project. I am a bit worried that changing to ggplot might add unforeseen difficulties with some of my other plots. It's a nice solution though.

Comment: I'm sorry I hadn't specified base R in the original post. If I can't accomplish this in base R, your example provides a great explanation on how to move forward using ggplot. Thanks.

Comment: Just in case there isn't a way to do this in base R, I have one basic question regarding your process. Up to this point I have been using CSV files for my reference data (not good, I know). I've looked around and it seems you can do something similar using ggplot. Is there a way to do something like that rather than copying and pasting in the values as is shown in your example?

Answer (score 2):

I'd propose a tidyverse solution. In this approach you first create a function which will compute and extract the needed statistics. Then you create a list-column with `nest`, `map` the function on that list, and `unnest` the result.

You can read more about this approach at http://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html.

```r
library(tidyverse)

# create function to retrieve fit and se
pred_fun <- function(df) {
  model <- loess(`15p5` ~ Period, df, weights = Total_5plus, span = .6)
  preds <- predict(model, se = T)

  data_frame(fit = preds[["fit"]],
             se = preds[["se.fit"]])
}

# nest, map and unnest fits
nested <- bind_rows(df_5k, df_5kz) %>% 
  group_by(origin) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(preds = map(data, pred_fun)) %>% 
  unnest(data, preds)


# plot result
ggplot(nested, aes(Period, `15p5`)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = fit - 1.96 * se, ymax = fit + 1.96 * se, fill = origin),
              alpha = .2) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(aes(y = fit, colour = origin)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(.3, 0)) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(.3, 0), breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(6)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  labs(x = "Years B.P.", y = expression(''[15]*'p'[5]))
```

[image]

Of course you can edit the colors of the groups, for example like so:

```r
cols <- c(df_5k = "blue", df_5kz = "skyblue")

ggplot...
...
scale_fill_manual(values = cols) +
scale_color_manual(values = cols)
```

### Edit:

Since I don't know, how to do what you want with base graphics, I'd try to make the plot look like base, using `ggthemes::theme_base` and changing the point type like this:

```r
ggplot(nested, aes(Period, `15p5`)) +
  ggthemes::theme_base() +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0.173, linetype = "dotted") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = c(-4700, -4000, -3000), linetype = "dotted") +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = fit - 1.96 * se, ymax = fit + 1.96 * se, fill = origin),
              alpha = .2) +
  geom_point(shape = 1) +
  geom_line(aes(y = fit, colour = origin)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(.3, 0)) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(.3, 0), breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(6)) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  labs(x = "Years B.P.", y = expression(''[15]*'p'[5]),
       colour = NULL, fill = NULL)
```

[image]

#### Data import

```r
df_5k <- "Period  15p5    Total_5plus
-4350   0.100529101 12.6
-3900   0.4 20
-3650   0.0625  9.6
-3900   0.126984127 16.8
-3958   0.133333333 5
-4350   0.150943396 10.6
-3400   0.146341463 8.2
-3650   0.255319149 9.4
-3400   0.222222222 9
-3500   0.245014245 39
-3600   0.125   8
-3808   0.1 20
-3900   0.160493827 18
-3958   0.238095238 7
-4058   0.2 5
-3500   0.086956522 28.75
-4117   0.141414141 6.6
-4350   0.171038825 31.76666667
-4350   0.166666667 6
-3650   0.143798024 30.36666667
-2715   0.137931034 7.25
-4350   0.235588972 26.6
-3500   0.228840125 79.75
-4350   0.041666667 8
-3650   0.174757282 20.6
-2715   0.377777778 11.25
-3500   0.2 7.5
-3650   0.078947368 7.6
-3400   0.208333333 24
-4233   0.184027778 19.2
-3650   0.285714286 12.6
-4350   0.166666667 6"

df_5k <- read_table2(df_5k) %>% 
  mutate(origin = "df_5k")

df_5kz <- "Period  15p5    Total_5plus
-4350   0.100529101 12.6
-4350   0   5
-3900   0.4 20
-3650   0.0625  9.6
-3400   0   6
-3900   0.126984127 16.8
-3958   0.133333333 5
-4350   0.150943396 10.6
-3400   0.146341463 8.2
-3650   0.255319149 9.4
-3400   0.222222222 9
-3500   0.245014245 39
-3600   0.125   8
-3650   0   28
-3808   0.1 20
-3900   0.160493827 18
-3958   0.238095238 7
-4058   0.2 5
-3500   0   25
-3500   0.086956522 28.75
-4117   0.141414141 6.6
-4350   0.171038825 31.76666667
-4350   0.166666667 6
-3650   0.143798024 30.36666667
-2715   0.137931034 7.25
-4350   0.235588972 26.6
-3500   0.228840125 79.75
-4350   0.041666667 8
-3500   0   5
-3650   0.174757282 20.6
-3800   0   9
-2715   0.377777778 11.25
-3500   0.2 7.5
-3650   0.078947368 7.6
-4117   0   8
-4350   0   8
-3400   0.208333333 24
-4233   0.184027778 19.2
-3025   0   7
-3650   0.285714286 12.6
-4350   0.166666667 6"

df_5kz <- read_table2(df_5kz) %>% 
  mutate(origin = "df_5kz")
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I appreciate your help. I haven't used tidyverse before, but it seems like a very streamlined approach. Unfortunately, I'd like to try to accomplish this in base R. I have a large number of plots and I haven't used ggplot before. I'm worried that the learning curve and possible complications with other plots might push me beyond my deadline.  I'm sorry I hadn't specified base R in the post. I haven't seen this method in other posts before, so I'm sure it will be useful to others looking for similar solutions. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just in case there isn't a way to do this in base R, I have one basic question regarding your process. Up to this point I have been using CSV files for my reference data (not good, I know). I've looked around and it seems you can do something similar using ggplot. Is there a way to do something like that rather than copying and pasting in the values as is shown in your example?

Comment: @Corey You can simply use base functions to import your data. If you want to buy into the tidyverse, take a look at the readr package: http://readr.tidyverse.org/. Just import the data with readr, transform it with dplyr and purrr, like I showed, and plot it with ggplot2.

Comment: @Corey I edited my post with a new version, which looks more like base graphics.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the help!